# Kotlin+Gradle runnable jar - dependency causing "Could not find or load main class"

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin

Gradle build file:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.41'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

group 'com.anivive'
version '0.1'

apply plugin: 'kotlin'

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin/'
    test.java.srcDirs += 'src/test/kotlin/'
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url "https://packagecloud.io/anivive/anivive/maven2"
    }
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'anivive:Import_Utils:1.2.44'
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

jar {
    baseName = 'XMLModelBuilder'
    version = '0.1'
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.anivive.Main'
    }
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
}
```

File structure:

```
src
 - main
   - kotlin
     - com
       - anivive
          - Main.kt
```

Main.kt:

```
package com.anivive

import com.anivive.util.ExampleClass

object Main {
    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        ExampleClass.exampleMethod()
    }
}
```

So, I'm trying to build a runnable jar file that will call a single method from a class in the dependency 'anivive:Import_Utils:1.2.44'.

If I remove the dependency, and change my main method to just `println("Test")`, the jar will run fine via `java -jar build/libs/jarFile.jar` and it will print out `Test`.

However, with the dependency included and when trying to call a function from it, I will get `Error: Could not find or load main class com.anivive.Main` whenever I try to run the Jar file. I suspect it has something to do with hosting the jar file on packagecloud, but I'm surprised this is a problem, considering I can run the program just fine from IntelliJ.

What gives?

Comment: Same problem here. I've checked the actual paths in the jar file and they are correct. It just can't find the class which makes me thing that the class path is wrong.

I'm using the Kotlin DSL for gradle. [Here is a gist of the config](https://gist.github.com/brokenthorn/307d02dd648be97c6c64769425309bbc).

Comment: @brokenthorn sorry, I never did solve this. I eventually gave up.

Comment: I used gradle's `application` plugin that creates a bundle called a distribution in `build\distributions` which is packaged correctly such that all dependencies are provided, plus there are two scripts in a packaged `bin` folder, one for Windows and one for *nixes which can be used to launch the app from a command line. Pretty neat! It even makes [deploying to Docker easier](https://github.com/brokenthorn/stockwebservice/blob/ad5239240b7a8c42c7de07c282d736ec085aaaa2/build.gradle.kts#L14) because you only need to add `ADD "./build/distributions/packagename-0.1.tar" /app` to your `Dockerfile`.

Comment: I couldn't write more text in my last comment, but the `ADD` line in a `Dockerfile` automatically extracts a tarball to the specified container path.